# Problems with <UITextinputDelegate> protocol implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextinput

What I am trying to implement is a `UITextField` that sees words as characters. Specifically, im trying to see the mathemathical expression sin( as one character for example. I thought to solve this problem by implementing my own UITextInputDelegate. However, the four required functions from this protocol never get called when I implement or adopt this protocol. I tried implementing it in the following ways:

By subclassing a `UITextField`.

```
@interface BIDUItextFieldDelegate : UITextField < UITextInputDelegate >
```

By subclassing a NSObject.

```
@interface BIDTextfieldInputDelegate : NSObject < UITextInputDelegate >
```

The corresponding .m file contains:

```
@implementation BIDTextfieldInputDelegate


- (void)selectionWillChange:(id <UITextInput>)textInput
{
    NSLog(@"sWill");
}

- (void)selectionDidChange:(id <UITextInput>)textInput
{
    NSLog(@"sDid");
}

- (void)textWillChange:(id <UITextInput>)textInput
{
    NSLog(@"tWill");
}

- (void)textDidChange:(id <UITextInput>)textInput
{
    NSLog(@"tDid");
}
```

For example for the second approach (via subclassing NSObject), I do the following in the (id) init method in an additional custom UITextfield class which is displayed within the app:

```
//textInputDel is an instance of the custom NSObject class that adopts the above UITextInputDelegate protocol
self.textInputDel = [[BIDTextfieldInputDelegate alloc] init];

self.inputDelegate = self.textFieldDel;
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or has a better solution?

Comment: http://apptree.net/parser.htm May help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment, I am using DDmathparser. Parsing itself all works fine, but for example being able to delete a few characters at the same time or restricted insertion possibilities within fixed words is more the problem I am dealing with at the moment.

Comment: You can find a workaround for the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158161/uitextinputdelegate-methods-not-functioning-correctly/27128185#27128185).

Answer (score 3):

`UITextInputDelegate` is not a protocol that *you* implement; rather, the system creates an object conforming to `UITextInputDelegate`, and assigns it as the `.inputDelegate` of a First Responder that conforms to `UITextInput`.

The methods of `UITextInputDelegate` are methods for *your UITextInput-conforming responder to call* on your `.inputDelegate` to inform it that you have changed your text or selection via means other than keyboard input.

Comment: NM, I misread the dates on this post and thought it was discussing problems with keyboard extensions using it.